# JavaScript: convert string to different format

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I am designing a timer. For that i want to convert the value the user types in to the input to a different format.

like this:

120000 => 12:00:00

34233 => 3:42:33

this is the JavaScript i have now:

```
$('input#time').focusout(function(){
    startTime = $(this).val();
    //here code that converts to different format
    $('input#time').val(startTime);
});
```

So, how do i convert it?

Comment: Did you try anything to solve this?

Comment: May i suggest that you put 3 input boxes instead of 1, one for each hours, minutes and seconds, then you can forget all the trouble that can come when users can freely put numbers. Each input will have its own min/max value making sure it converts to a real time ... this is how I would do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Regex and `split`:

```
function convertTime(str){
    return str.split(/(?=(?:..)*$)/).join(':');
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function convertTime(str) {
  return str.split(/(?=(?:..)*$)/).join(':');
}

$('input#time').on('input',function() {
  startTime = $(this).val();
  $('input#result').val(convertTime(startTime));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="time" value="120000" /> <br/>
<input id="result" value="12:00:00" />
```

Comment: You need to set a max of 6 numbers or time looks weird :) ... unless fractions is needed

Comment: @LGSon Yes, and also to prevent users from entering things like 328263

Comment: wow thank you! better than i expected. the type='number' property is also nice. I didn't even knew that existed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in a timer, I suggest you to use the momentJS library (http://momentjs.com/docs/). It covers all of your current and future needs.
In your specific situation, you should:

1. Download the plugin to your JS folder
2. Link the plugin in your HTML, like this:

   `<script src="path/to/your/JS/folder/moment.min.js" />`
3. Convert the value using moment:

   `startTime = moment(startTime, "HHmmss").format("HH:mm:ss");`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```js
String.prototype.formatNumber = function() {
  return this.replace(/^((?:\d{1})?)((?:\d{2})+)$/, function(i, i1, i2) {
    return (i1.length ? i1 + ':' : '') + i2.match(/\d{2}/g).join(':');
  })
};

$('#text').on('input', function() {
  $('#op').text(this.value.formatNumber());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text"/>

<div id=op></div>
```

or

```js
String.prototype.formatNumber = function() {
  return this.match(/^.(?=(.{2})+$)|.{2}/g).join(':')
}

$('#text').on('input', function() {
  $('#op').text(this.value.formatNumber());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text"/>

<div id=op></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the time with following format, would be much easier: HH:MM:SS

```
String t= "15:30:18";
Time.valueof(t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var input = "120000".split("");
var part;
var result = "";
var count = 1;
while(part = input.pop()) {
  result = part+result;
  if((count%2 === 0) && input.length>0) {
    result = ":"+result;
  }
  count++;
}
```